# iOS 10.0 Speech Recognition Error kAFAssistantErrorDomain

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, sfspeechrecognizer

I try using speech recognition as below

```
    let urlpath = Bundle.main().pathForResource("myvoice2", ofType: "m4a")
    let url:URL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: urlpath!)

    let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
    let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: url)
    recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
        print (result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)

    })
```

The result is nil, I debug and see the error as below

`Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1101 "(null)"`

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you add `NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription` key in Info.Plist?

Comment: I have already added, but the same issue.

Comment: Having the same reaction with the simulator. When I opened the project "SpeakToMe" Xcode 8 Beta requested a conversion from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.  I did convert it... What did everyone do? And does anyone think this conversion might be the problem?

Comment: 1101 seems to happen when using simulator, have not seen it on a device

Comment: 1101 happened on the device just now, running iOS 13.5.1

Comment: In my case I was stopping audioEngine without checking it is currently running or not. I just fixed with this code: if self.audioEngine.isRunning {
                   self.audioEngine.stop()
                    self.recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
                }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have the same error, but identical code worked fine on device. So, install iOS 10 beta on a physical device and run your code. Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { authStatus in
    if authStatus == SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
        if let path = Bundle.main().urlForResource("test", withExtension: "m4a") {
            let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
            let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: path)
            recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("There was an error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print (result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[I wrote about this in more detail here.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/ios10)

Comment: That's right, thanks @TwoStraws. The issue occurs on Simulator, It worked on real device.

Comment: I've been testing on real device and the issue is still there. It's like the App is running for a while but it stopped with the same error: 

Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=203 "Timeout" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Timeout, NSUnderlyingError=0x17004ff30 {Error Domain=SiriSpeechErrorDomain Code=100 "(null)"}}

Any thought about this? Thanks

Comment: @VaVisal the timeout error is caused by never calling endAudio method of the SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest instance.

Comment: Anyone fix Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=203 ?